# CNTK TransferLearning sample - Running out of memory on my Geforce 960M

Tags: deep-learning, gpu, cntk

My Nvidia Geforce 960M has 2 GB of dedicated graphics memory. But when I try and run the sample (*CNTK-Samples-2-4\Examples\Image\TransferLearning*), I get the following CUDA memory allocation error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "TransferLearning.py", line
>   217, in 
>       max_epochs, freeze=freeze_weights)   File "TransferLearning.py", line 130, in train_model
>       trainer.train_minibatch(data)                                    # update model with it   File
>   "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\train\trainer.py",
>   line 181, in train_minibatch
>       arguments, device)   File "C:\Users\Dell\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line
>   2975, in train_minibatch_overload_for_minibatchdata
>       return _cntk_py.Trainer_train_minibatch_overload_for_minibatchdata(self, *args) RuntimeError: CUDA failure 2: out of memory ; GPU=0 ; hostname=DESKTOP-IA3HLGI ; expr=cudaMalloc((void**) &deviceBufferPtr,
>   sizeof(AllocatedElemType) * AsMultipleOf(numElements, 2)) [CALL STACK]
>       > Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::CudaTimer::  Stop
>       - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::CudaTimer::  Stop (x2)
>       - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::GPUMatrix::  Resize
>       - Microsoft::MSR::CNTK::Matrix::  Resize
>       - std::enable_shared_from_this::enable_shared_from_this
>       - std::enable_shared_from_this::  shared_from_this (x3)
>       - CNTK::Internal::  UseSparseGradientAggregationInDataParallelSGD
>       - CNTK::  CreateTrainer
>       - CNTK::Trainer::  TotalNumberOfUnitsSeen
>       - CNTK::Trainer::  TrainMinibatch (x2)
>       - PyInit__cntk_py (x2)

Is there a way to run this sample using the GPU? Is there a configuration for CUDA/CNTK for memory? Do I need to change image size and/or batch size?

Comment: don't know if there is a GPU setting but try reducing the mini batch size, the source code lists the variable as 'mb_size = 50' on line 41

Answer (score 0):

thanks NiallJG. Changing the batch size did the trick. I tried mb_size=30 and it works!